# MS Access version of =COUNTIF($X$X:X2,X2)?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to create a report in MS Access (2007-2016) that will generate a column with sequential numbering of duplicate records similar to a countif statement in excel. The resulting data would look similar to this.

```
Work Order      Activity      SCH Date      Count
DS18820442  DS18820442-1  3/9/2020      1
DS18823101  DS18823101-1  3/11/2020     1         
DS18823101  DS18823101-1  3/12/2020     2         
DS17914849  DS17914849-1  1/3/2020      1        
DS17914849  DS17914849-1  1/6/2020      2        
DS17914849  DS17914849-1  1/7/2020      3
```

Is there a similar way to do this easily in access?

Comment: You need a column that specifies the ordering for the rows.  Otherwise this cannot really be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the information in your comments, try the following modification of Gordon's code:

```
select 
    t.*, 
    (
        select count(*) from [12_6] t2 
        where 
            t2.[Work Order] = t.[Work Order] and 
            t2.[Activity] = t.[Activity] and
            t2.[Scheduled_Date] <= t.[Scheduled_Date]
    ) 
    as seqcol
into test_sequence 
from [12_6] t;
```

Here, the query is using a correlated subquery: for every record in your table, the subquery calculates the number of records within the table with the same `Work Order` and `Activity` value as the current record, and for which the `Scheduled_Date` is less than that of the current record (i.e. essentially "ranking" the current record by `Scheduled_Date`)

Comment: Thanks, this worked exactly as needed! I have a question if you could answer so I can better understand it. Is this pretty much just a self join? I'm a little confused as to what exactly the date line is doing. Just referencing the same column to create an order from oldest to newest?

Comment: It's a correlated subquery: for every record in your table, the subquery calculates the number of records within the table with the same `Work Order` and `Activity` value as the current record, and for which the `Scheduled_Date` is less than that of the current record (i.e. essentially "ranking" the current record by `Scheduled_Date`) I have added this information to my answer as well.

Comment: Thank you very much for expanding on this, I will try to learn from this for future instances.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a column that specifies the ordering of the rows, you can use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (select count(*)
        from t as t2
        where t2.code = t.code and t2.activity = t.activity and
              t2.? <= t.?
       ) as newcol
from t;
```

The `?` is for the column that specifies the ordering.

Comment: I added a date column to use for ordering, but I believe i probably messed something up.  Qry ended up erroring out on me.                                                             SELECT [12_6}.*,
(select count (*)
from [12_6] as [12_6_2]
where [12_6_2].[Work Order] = [12_6].[Work Order] 
and [12_6_2].[Activity] = [12_6].[Activity] 
and [12_6_2].[Scheduled_Date] <= [12_6].[Scheduled_Date])
As SEQCOL
INTO TEST_SEQUENCE
FROM 12_26;

Comment: @Cri . . . Interesting that you changed the names of the columns thereby invalidating this answer.

Comment: Apologies, I renamed it In my personal table to reflect business names then updated with date as you suggested. Not meant to partially invalidate your help